TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types - while performing Mann-Whitney U test
I have two data frames,primary_tumor_df and healthy_tissue_df to perform the Mann-Whitney U test. I have also removed nan values from both the data frames.
Structure of primary_tumor_df.

Structure of healthy_tissue_df.

primary_tumor_df.dropna(inplace=True)
healthy_tissue_df.dropna(inplace=True)

This shows that there are no nan or null values.


But while performing the test it gives me the following error:
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
p_value_dict = {}
for gene in primary_tumor_df.columns:
stats, p_value = mannwhitneyu(primary_tumor_df[gene], healthy_tissue_df[gene],
                              alternative='two-sided')

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 4
      2 p_value_dict = {}
      3 for gene in primary_tumor_df.columns:
----> 4     stats, p_value = mannwhitneyu(primary_tumor_df[gene],
      5                                  healthy_tissue_df[gene],
      6                                  alternative='two-sided')
      7     p_value_dict[gene] = p_value
      9 # converting into DataFrame

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/stats/_axis_nan_policy.py:502, in _axis_nan_policy_factory.<locals>.axis_nan_policy_decorator.<locals>.axis_nan_policy_wrapper(***failed resolving arguments***)
    500 if sentinel:
    501     samples = _remove_sentinel(samples, paired, sentinel)
--> 502 res = hypotest_fun_out(*samples, **kwds)
    503 res = result_to_tuple(res)
    504 res = _add_reduced_axes(res, reduced_axes, keepdims)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/stats/_mannwhitneyu.py:460, in mannwhitneyu(x, y, use_continuity, alternative, axis, method)
    249 @_axis_nan_policy_factory(MannwhitneyuResult, n_samples=2)
    250 def mannwhitneyu(x, y, use_continuity=True, alternative="two-sided",
    251                  axis=0, method="auto"):
    252     r'''Perform the Mann-Whitney U rank test on two independent samples.
    253 
    254     The Mann-Whitney U test is a nonparametric test of the null hypothesis
   (...)
    456 
    457     '''
    459     x, y, use_continuity, alternative, axis_int, method = (
--> 460         _mwu_input_validation(x, y, use_continuity, alternative, axis, method))
    462     x, y, xy = _broadcast_concatenate(x, y, axis)
    464     n1, n2 = x.shape[-1], y.shape[-1]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/stats/_mannwhitneyu.py:200, in _mwu_input_validation(x, y, use_continuity, alternative, axis, method)
    198 # Would use np.asarray_chkfinite, but infs are OK
    199 x, y = np.atleast_1d(x), np.atleast_1d(y)
--> 200 if np.isnan(x).any() or np.isnan(y).any():
    201     raise ValueError('`x` and `y` must not contain NaNs.')
    202 if np.size(x) == 0 or np.size(y) == 0:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Even though there aren't any nan values in the data frame why is it producing the
error?

It's not complaining that there are NaNs. It's trying to check whether there are NaNs, and it can't check on that dtype. What is the dtype of the data you're passing into mannwhitneyu? (check e.g. primary_tumor_df[gene]. dtype)

I believe the pandas isnull can handle more dtypes than np.isnan.  isnan is a float test. int should cast safely to float, but non-numeric types can't.

@MattHaberland
python for gene in primary_tumor_df.columns:     print(primary_tumor_df[gene].dtype) 
This outputs as object

That was a clicking point. I converted it to numeric and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much @MattHaberland
Can you also share with me, how to know which line meant to say about the dtype?

I wrote this up as an answer so others can easily find the solution to similar problems in the future. I hope it also addresses your follow-up question.

The problem is that at least one column of primary_tumor_df or healthy_tissue_df has object dtype, not that either has a NaN.
You can tell because the line that ultimately raises the error:
if np.isnan(x).any() or np.isnan(y).any():

is checking for NaNs in the inputs x and y of mannwhitneyu, and it complains that
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

In plain English, that's just "isnan doesn't work on the type of data you're providing, and it couldn't safely cast the data to a type isnan does work with."
This error isn't raised for numeric data types.
import numpy as np
for dtype in [np.uint8, np.int16, np.float32, np.complex64]:
    x = np.arange(10., dtype=np.float64)
    np.isnan(x)  # no error

whether or not they have NaNs:
y = x.copy()
y[0] = np.nan
np.isnan(y)  # no error

After all, the purpose of isnan is to find NaNs and report where they are with a boolean array.
The problem is for non-numeric dtypes.
x = np.asarray(x, dtype=object)
np.isnan(x)  # error

The error said it couldn't safely be cast to a type isnan works with, but that doesn't mean it can't be cast. If the data really is numeric but pandas has it stored as some more general type of object, you should be able to fix the problem by converting it to a floating point type before passing it into SciPy.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(435982435982345)
primary_tumor_df = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((10, 3)).astype(object))
healthy_tissue_df = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((10, 3)).astype(object))

# generates your error:
# for gene in primary_tumor_df.columns:
#     res = stats.mannwhitneyu(primary_tumor_df[gene],
#                              healthy_tissue_df[gene],
#                              alternative='two-sided')

# no error    
for gene in primary_tumor_df.columns:
    res = stats.mannwhitneyu(primary_tumor_df[gene].astype(np.float64),
                             healthy_tissue_df[gene].astype(np.float64),
                             alternative='two-sided')


That said, you don't even need the for loop. mannwhitneyu is vectorized, and by default it works along axis=0 - your columns.
res = stats.mannwhitneyu(primary_tumor_df.astype(np.float64),
                         healthy_tissue_df.astype(np.float64),
                         alternative='two-sided')

